# Issue in displaying web page in laravel

Tags: laravel

I am facing one issue.Instead of displaying web page in laravel It is displaying like image in text which is attached[image] by me.

Comment: it looks that you may forget to set your blade extension as `.blade.php` but for insurance add your code

Comment: thank you very much.Issue is  resolved. i was stucking in this basic issue

Comment: i forget it a lot of time to :)